# Reinstalling broken kernel 4.9.0.9 on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg, initramfs

Following recent Intel chip bugs I upgraded my Debian Stretch server. Microcode updated OK, but `update-initramfs` was hanging. So I killed it and tried to remove the kernel before trying to reinstall it. The removal process is hanging too:

```
% dpkg --remove --force-depends linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64
dpkg: linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64.
(Reading database ... 228637 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64 (4.9.168-1+deb9u2) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-9-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-8-amd64
```

It appears to hang on `postrm` script:

```
% ps axuw |grep dpkg
root       467  0.0  0.0  12780   972 pts/8    S+   21:25   0:00 grep dpkg
root     32074  0.1  0.1  65668 52804 pts/7    S+   21:23   0:00 dpkg --remove --force-depends linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64
root     32075  0.0  0.0   4276   708 pts/7    S+   21:23   0:00 /bin/sh -e /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.9.0-9-amd64.postrm remove
```

How can I fix that?